# num_rows return ZERO all the time in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, mysql-num-rows

I have a simple code in CI Model for Login BUT it always return 0.

```
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('cms_users');
     $this->db->where('username', "admin");
     $this->db->where('password', "admin01");
     $query = $this->db->get();
     echo $query->num_rows();exit;
```

It always print 0.

When i try `echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();exit;` and run in phpmyadmin it return one value.

Comment: Did you check in your DB that you actually have a user='admin' with password='admin01' in your table cms_users?

Comment: in fact you don't need $this->db->select('*');, beacuse the $this->db->get() do that by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think because you are **echoing** instead of **return**

And you have exit on there as well I would not use **exit;**.

Model: **User_model.php**

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public function count() {
       $this->db->where('username', "admin");
       $this->db->where('password', "admin01");
       $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'cms_users');
       return $query->num_rows();
    }

}
```

Controller: **Weclome.php**

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('user_model');
   }

   public function index() {
      $data['user_total'] = $this->user_model->count();

      $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
   }

}
```